# How to loop from an array received as a parameter in plpgsql function?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, function, loops, plpgsql

I'm kinda new into pgplsql and so far I have to create a function that loops an array that is received as a function.

The main idea of the function is to insert new records into a table that maps each id contained in the array received with a new formatted id, the format depends on the second parameter received and return the table "idsTable".

The problem is that when I try to create the function it sends me an error:

ERROR:  loop variable of FOREACH must be a known variable or list of variables
LINE 38: FOREACH objectid IN ARRAY idsList LOOP

I'm not sure if I have to declare the objectid variable cause in the examples that I have seen they didn't.

So far I have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createId(idsList varchar[], objectType varchar)
RETURNS TABLE(original_id varchar, new_id char) as
$$
BEGIN
IF LOWER(objectType) = 'global' THEN
    FOREACH objectid IN ARRAY idsList LOOP
        INSERT INTO idsTable(original_id, new_id)
        VALUES(objectid, 'GID'||nextval('mapSquema.globalid')::TEXT);
    END LOOP;
ELSE
    FOREACH objectid IN ARRAY idsList LOOP
        INSERT INTO idsTable(original_id, new_id)
        VALUES(objectid, 'ORG'||nextval('mapSquema.globalid')::TEXT);
    END LOOP;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

edit: I haven't add the part where the idsTable is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unrelated, but: you don't really need a loop for that. And you can simplify the function by only writing the `INSERT` once. You also forgot to return something from your function. As it is declared as `returns table` that is required:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createid(idslist varchar[], objecttype varchar)
   RETURNS TABLE(original_id varchar, new_id varchar) as
$$
declare 
  l_prefix text;
BEGIN
  IF LOWER(objectType) = 'global' THEN
    l_prefix := 'GID';
  ELSE
    l_prefix := 'ORG';
  END IF;

  RETURN QUERY --<< return the result of the insert
  INSERT INTO idstable(original_id, new_id)
  select t.x, l_prefix||nextval('mapSquema.globalid')::TEXT
  from unnest(idslist) as t(x)
  returning *

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks that's a nice advice, I will give it a try!